# CodeIgniter - error with login system ( HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found on IIS)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter, so I just follow tutorial to create login system to get myself familiar with CodeIgniter MVC. While working on it, I got HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found on IIS after I click on the login button.

Controller

```
<?php 
    class LoginController extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){
            $this->load->helper(array('form'));
            $this->load->view('login');
    }

        public function checkLogin(){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_verifyUser');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                $this->load->view('login');
            }else{
                redirect('HomeController/index');
            }   
        }

        public function verifyUser(){
            $name = $this->input->post('username');
            $pass = $this->input->post('password');

            $this->load->model('LoginModel');
            if($this->LoginModel->login('$name, $pass')){
                return true;
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect email or password. Please try again');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Model

```
<?php
    class LoginModel extends CI_Model{
        function login($name, $pass){
            $this->db->select('name, pass');
            $this->db->from('members');
            $this->db->where('name', $name);
            $this->db->where('pass', $pass);

            $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

View

```
<head>
    <title>Login System with CI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors();?>
    <?php echo form_open('LoginController/checkLogin');?>
        Username: </br>
        <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
        Password: </br>
        <input type='password' name='password'/><br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I don't know what I am missing here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/create-login-and-registration-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try this one:

```
<head>
<title>Login System with CI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors();?>
    <?php echo form_open('LoginController/index.php/checkLogin');?>
        Username: </br>
        <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
        Password: </br>
        <input type='password' name='password'/><br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: did you create `HomeController` ?

Comment: yes i did. <?php 
class HomeController extends CI_Controller{
 public function index(){
  $this->load->view('home');
 }
}
?>

Comment: Try modify: `redirect('HomeController/index.php')`;

Comment: I tried it now, its still not working. Do you think it can be a routes problem?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'LoginController';

Comment: Try $this->load->helper('form') instead of $this->load->helper(array('form'))

Comment: tried it already, still not work. thank you @Imran for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## Login

```
 <?php echo validation_errors();?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('LoginController/checkLogin');?>">

        Username: </br>
        <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
        Password: </br>
        <input type='password' name='password'/><br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and modal seems true. You can try this on your view ;

```
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('LoginController/checkLogin');?>">

        Username: </br>
        <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
        Password: </br>
        <input type='password' name='password'/><br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
    </form>
</body>
```

And what is your $config['base_url'] in config.php ?

Did you change .htaccess or remove index.php  ?

Comment: here is my $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: no i haven't changed .htaccess or remove index.php yet, I don't really know how to do it to be honest.

Comment: Can you try to post with full url in <form> tag ?   <form method="POST" action="http:// yourdomain.com/index.php/LoginController/checkLogin">  There is no blank after http://